# Spring Webflux - performance of event loop between real hardware cores and virtual cores

Tags: java, performance, spring-webflux

A quick question regarding performance of the Spring Webflux event loop.

We performed some rudimentary performance test with gatling + JMeter + Yourkit for Spring Webflux.

We noticed some major difference between two scenarios:

1 - Scenario 1, Our test setup: send N amount of HTTP request to the Webflux web app deployed on a **bare metal** host. We took a MacBook Pro out of the box with 8 cores. We repeated the same test on a physical server with 8 cores. The test result between the two matches. We saw event loop taking care of switching cores between the IO, we saw Webflux shine and are very happy.

2 - Scenario 2, Exact same test, except it is now running on **virtual** cores. By virtual cores, I mean we request VMs with 8 cores, or we request 8 CPUs to Kubernetes. Here, we saw a major drop in performance.

Just a simple question, is there supposed to be a difference when Webflux and the event loop is running between bare metal physical cores, and when running with virtual ones?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your operations will done by real core in bare metal and virtual mode. The difference is that in virtual cores we have multi tenancy on real cores and there are other tasks which must be done by real core.

Your performance is also depend to other factors such as Network, Disk IO and so on. But if we suppose they are fixed, probably you reach an equal result on both if there is no other VM or tasks along side your VM. However in many cases you have interference with other tasks in virtualization mode and you take lower performance related to bare metal. Furthermore, in virtual mode you may take different performance in every single run.

Take a look at [Bare Metal vs. Virtualization: What Performs Better?](https://phoenixnap.com/blog/bare-metal-vs-virtualization) and see the performance comparison depicted at the end.